# model-viewer: how to scale 3D object to fill the container

Tags: 3d, resize, responsive, scale, model-viewer

I have this 3D model that loads very small in a pretty big model-viewer canvas
[image]

I want it to load bigger in order to at least fit the height of the rectangle, is there a setting in model-viewer for this?

The model is scaled in Blender to be pretty big so I am sure the scale of the actual model isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

fixed, i just played around with the camera-orbit property